# How to set conditional disable in an input field?

Tags: input, conditional-rendering

````
```<input ref={refName} disabled value={user.displayName} type="text" placeholder="name"  />```
````

> the input field gets its value from useAuthState. I wanted to disable the field depending on if a button was pressed or not.  (like onClick disable)

Comment: did you want to tag this with `react`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is using React, you need to track the state, including whether it should be disabled. You cannot do any modifications to the DOM directly, as the DOM is regenerated repeatedly (not constantly, but sometimes when you don't expect it).

How to do that depends on if you have a functional component or a class component, but bottom line is, put a `disabled` value into your state, and set that value in your `onClick`, then use that value in your render.

Using the `ref`, it is possible to access the generated element, usually from `useEffect`, but if you use it from a handler like `onClick`, it may not be permanent, and might get reset back to enabled by a render of an element higher up in the DOM.

Consider this psuedo code, you can work out details:

```
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

function onClick() {
  setDisabled(true)
}

<input ref={refName} disabled={isDisabled} value={user.displayName} type="text" placeholder="name"  />

<button onClick={onClick}>Disable Input</button>
```